# How do I remove page 2 of this page when printing?

Tags: html, css, printing, media, responsive

I've been trying a few different things to remove the second page on this page when printing. Is there something I am doing wrong?

I've placed:
**page-break-after: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;**
On to the last element on the page, so I'm just a little confused on what I'm doing wrong here.

Any suggestions would be appericated.

See the code below...

```css
/* Custom Hero Styles */
    
    .subhero1 {
        background: #000;
        height: 400px !important;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 650px) {
        .subhero1 {
            background: #000;
            height: 250px !important;
        }
        .subhero__content-container {
            color: #fff !important;
        }
    }
    /* Custom Cards */
    
    .obs__fullcardheader {
        border-bottom: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        font-size: 3.5vmax;
    }
    
    .obs__fullcard {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 5px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .obs__cardheader img {
        max-width: 20%;
    }
    
    .obs__card {
        height: 300px;
    }
    
    .fullcardwrapper {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        padding-top: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    .cardwrapper {
        padding: 30px;
    }
    
    .appicons img {
        max-width: 160px;
    }
    
    .small__font {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    
    .obs__cardline2 {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .obs__cardline1 a {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .obs__cardline1 a:hover {
        color: #565656;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #565656;
    }
    
    .obs__cardline2 a {
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .obs__cardline2 a:hover {
        color: #565656;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #565656;
    }
    
    .coupon-btn-wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 300px;
    }
    
    .print-exclusions {
        display: none;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 650px) {
        .obs__card {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .obs__cardheader img {
            max-width: 15% !important;
        }
        .obs__fullcardheader {
            font-size: 4.5vmax;
        }
        .obs__couponhero-line1 {
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 1050px) {
        .obs__card {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
        }
        .obs__cardheader img {
            max-width: 10%;
        }
        .cardwrapper {
            padding: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
        .fullcardwrapper {
            padding-top: 10px;
            background: #fff;
        }
        .obs__fullcard {
            border: 1px solid #eee;
        }
        .obs__fullcardheader {
            font-size: 4.5vmax;
        }
        .coupon-btn-wrapper {
            max-width: 280px;
        }
    }
    
    .obs__couponhero-line1 {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .obs__couponhero-line2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .obs__couponhero-barcode {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .obs__couponhero-line3 {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
    
    .couponlinks a {
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    
    @media print {
        @page {
            size: landscape
        }
        .obs__card {
            width: 33%;
            height: 250px;
        }
        .head-main,
        .obs__cardline2,
        .appicons,
        .cust_service_headline,
        .obs__accordion,
        .coupon-btn-wrapper {
            display: none;
        }
        .obs__fullcard {
            height: 260px;
        }
        .cardwrapper {
            margin-top: 10px;
            max-width: 97.8%;
        }
        .obs__cardheader img {
            max-width: 25%;
        }
        footer {
            display: none;
        }
        .print-exclusions {
            display: block;
            padding-left: 14px;
            margin-top: -115px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            page-break-after: avoid;
            page-break-inside: avoid;
        }
        .obs__fullcard {
            width: 110%;
        }
        .obs-3 {
            clear: none;
        }
        @page {
            margin: 0;
        }
        body {
            margin: 1.6cm;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://media.offbroadwayshoes.com/css/obframe.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="frame fullcardwrapper">
    <div class="obs__max1200">
        <div class="obs__cards">
            <div class="obs__fullcard">
                <div class="obs__cardinner">
                    <div class="obs__fullcardheader">@@offer@@</div>
                    <div class="obs__couponhero-line1"><span class="new-line-mob">PLUS, BUY ONE, GET ONE</span> <span class="new-line-mob">50% OFF* YOUR 2ND PAIR</span>
                        <br /> *EXCLUSIONS APPLY</div>
                    <div class="obs__couponhero-line2">@@tatic@@ &middot; VALID THRU @@valid@@</div>
                    <div class="obs__couponhero-barcode">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="obs__couponhero-line3">@@ifonline@@ <font style="font-weight:bold;">@@onlinecode@@</font></div>
                    <div class="obs__cardline3">
                        <div class="coupon-btn-wrapper">
                            <div class="obs-2-static couponlinks" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">FIND YOUR STORE</a></div>
                            <div class="obs-2-static couponlinks" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">PRINT COUPON</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="frame cardwrapper bg-split__greytowhite">
    <div class="obs__max1440">
        <div class="obs__cards">
            <div class="obs__card">
                <div class="obs__cardinner">
                    <div class="obs__cardheader"><img src="https://media.offbroadwayshoes.com/icons/bogo.svg" alt="" />
                        <br /> BOGO 50% OFF*</div>
                    <div class="obs__cardline1">Buy One, Get One 50%
                        <br /> Off Your 2ND Pair</div>
                    <div class="obs__cardline2"><a data-exctarget="#1">SEE DETAILS</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="obs__card">
                <div class="obs__cardinner">
                    <div class="obs__cardheader"><img src="https://media.offbroadwayshoes.com/icons/free-shipping.svg" alt="" />
                        <br /> FREE SHIPPING</div>
                    <div class="obs__cardline1">Get Free Shipping
                        <br /> on Orders $50 or More!</div>
                    <div class="obs__cardline2"><a data-exctarget="#2">SEE DETAILS</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="obs__card">
                <div class="obs__cardinner">
                    <div class="obs__cardheader"><img src="//media.offbroadwayshoes.com/icons/mobile-app.svg" alt="" />
                        <br /> DOWNLOAD THE APP</div>
                    <div class="obs__cardline1">Shopping at your finger tips! <a>Learn More</a>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="frame">
    <div class="obs__max1440">
        <div class="obs__spacer50 obs__mob-spacer20">&nbsp;</div> <span class="cust_service_headline rightsideheading">Details & Exclusions</span>
        <div class="obs__spacer10">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="obs__accordion js-obs__accordion">
            <div class="obs__accordion__item js-obs__accordion-item">
                <div class="obs__accordion-header js-obs__accordion-header">Coupon Exclusions</div>
                <div class="obs__accordion-body js-obs__accordion-body">
                    <div class="obs__accordion-body__contents">*Limit one coupon per transaction. COUPON MAY ONLY BE USED ONCE AND MAY NOT BE MODIFIED, COPIED OR UPLOADED. Excludes Flash Sales, special promotional events. Must present coupon at time of purchase, cannot be combined with other coupons or used for the purchase of Gift Card(s) and is not redeemable for cash. Offer excluded on certain styles and brands, including but not limited to: Adidas, Asics, Bear Paw, Birkenstock, Converse, Keds, Merrell, Puma, Rainbow, Reebok, Rockport, Saucony, Sperry, Teva, Koolaburra by Ugg, Tommy Hilfiger Kids’, online Timberland & Timberland Pro, plus all Nike styles. Discount is taken before taxes. CAN BE COMBINED WITH EARNED QUALIFYING REWARDS DOLLARS BUT NOT OTHER REWARDS COUPON OFFERS. See store associate for details.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of obs__accordion item -->
            <div class="obs__accordion__item js-obs__accordion-item">
                <div class="obs__accordion-header js-obs__accordion-header" id="1">BOGO 50% OFF 2ND PAIR</div>
                <div class="obs__accordion-body js-obs__accordion-body">
                    <div class="obs__accordion-body__contents">*2nd pair must be of equal or lesser value. Excludes BOGO Free styles, Flash Sales, special promotional events, accessories and certain other styles, including but not limited to adidas, Asics, Bear Paw, Birkenstock, Converse, Keds, Koolaburra by Ugg, Merrell, Puma, Rainbow, Reebok, Rockport, Saucony, Sperry, Teva, Tommy Hilfiger Kids’, online Timberland & Timberland Pro, plus all Nike styles.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of obs__accordion item -->
            <div class="obs__accordion__item js-obs__accordion-item">
                <div class="obs__accordion-header js-obs__accordion-header" id="2">Free Shipping</div>
                <div class="obs__accordion-body js-obs__accordion-body">
                    <div class="obs__accordion-body__contents">Free economy shipping offer valid on orders with a subtotal over $50 after all discounts are applied. (Subtotal does not include tax or shipping fees)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of obs__accordion item -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of obs__accordion item -->
        <!-- end of obs__accordion -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="obs__spacer50 obs__mob-spacer20">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="print-exclusions">
    <div class="obs-3">
        <p class="obs__bold">COUPON EXCLUSIONS
            <p>
                <p style="font-size:8px;">*Limit one coupon per transaction. COUPON MAY ONLY BE USED ONCE AND MAY NOT BE MODIFIED, COPIED OR UPLOADED. Excludes Flash Sales, special promotional events. Must present coupon at time of purchase, cannot be combined with other coupons or used for the purchase of Gift Card(s) and is not redeemable for cash. Offer excluded on certain styles and brands, including but not limited to: Adidas, Asics, Bear Paw, Birkenstock, Converse, Keds, Merrell, Puma, Rainbow, Reebok, Rockport, Saucony, Sperry, Teva, Koolaburra by Ugg, Tommy Hilfiger Kids’, online Timberland & Timberland Pro, plus all Nike styles. Discount is taken before taxes. CAN BE COMBINED WITH EARNED QUALIFYING REWARDS DOLLARS BUT NOT OTHER REWARDS COUPON OFFERS. See store associate for details.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="obs-3">
        <p class="obs__bold">BOGO 50% OFF 2ND PAIR
            <p>
                <p style="font-size:8px;">*2nd pair must be of equal or lesser value. Excludes BOGO Free styles, Flash Sales, special promotional events, accessories and certain other styles, including but not limited to adidas, Asics, Bear Paw, Birkenstock, Converse, Keds, Koolaburra by Ugg, Merrell, Puma, Rainbow, Reebok, Rockport, Saucony, Sperry, Teva, Tommy Hilfiger Kids’, online Timberland & Timberland Pro, plus all Nike styles.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="obs-3">
        <p class="obs__bold">FREE SHIPPING
            <p>
                <p style="font-size:8px;">Free economy shipping offer valid on orders with a subtotal over $50 after all discounts are applied. (Subtotal does not include tax or shipping fees)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.print-exclusions {
        display: none;
    }` and then `.print-exclusions {
            display: block;`

Comment: Its already like that. Line 93, display: none -- Line 201, display: block

Comment: Yeah - that is your problem I believe

Comment: So what’s a way around it because I’m trying to simply show some simpler styles on print vs what’s already there. Why would a display none and display block cause it to be a second page? Also what’s your suggestion?

Comment: Changed the on the @print styles from display:block to display:inline-block. Which fixed my issue. Still don't understand how or why that fixed it, but it did. Thanks CSS.

Comment: I suspect I misunderstood. I saw the display:none and thought you wanted to hide them when printing. But you wanted to show -exclusions when printing?

Comment: Yes but without creating a second page. It was creating a blank page.

Comment: Ahh, so it pushed down empty content